# Place two DoubleClick for Publisher ads in one page

Tags: google-search-console, google-adsense, google-dfp, doubleclick-ad-exchange

I'd like to place two DoubleClick for Publisher ad blocks within one blog-post.

Do I have to create two ad units or may I re-use one for that purpose?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create two ad units and then generate tags for the page that include *both* those units.

When DFP gives you tags for the page there will then be three parts to it:

- A JavaScript snippet to place in the head.
- A snippet to place where the first ad goes on the page.
- A snippet to place where the second ad goes on the page.